# Set background drawable (Programmatically s)?

Tags: android

In my application I have something like this:

`Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
ProgressBar pb1  = new ProgressBar(this);
playBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(pb1);`

But this is not working. And I know why, - pb1 is not a drawable. But how otherwise I can set the background of my play button to the progress bar? I use a programmatic way of creating a progress bar and I have a play button in my .xml resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you really can't do what you're trying to do: there is no way to use one View as the background of another View.

What you can do is something similar to what the Android battery meter in the notification area does: make a number of drawables (I think the battery meter uses 5 or 6 different images, 1 for each stage of the recharge process) and then use a timer or external events to switch the background drawable for your button: this simulates a progress meter.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This won't be easy... I have a streaming player with a lot of methods. When the song is downloading, the progress bar is displayed separately in the same row previous, play, and next buttons are displayed. But it does not look beautiful... When the song is downloading, I want to replace the Play button with a progress bar. When it is downloaded, the Play button replaces the progress bar back.

Comment: Then the visibility of the Play button to `GONE` using `setVisibility` and the visibility of the ProgressBar to `VISIBLE` while playing; then set the play button to `VISIBLE and the ProgressBar to `GONE` when not playing.

Comment: Ah, you're trying to replace, NOT set it as a background. Put both the progress bar and the play button in a ViewSwitcher (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) and put that where the play button is right now. You can then flip from one to the other on demand.

Comment: @Joseph Earl, sounds nice, I'll try to do it, though I'm not sure where to place the progress bar initially.

Comment: The ViewSwitcher takes care of the positioning: they occupy the exact same space, and only one is visible at a time.

Comment: @Joseph Earl, I did what you said. in onBuffering() I set the visibility of progress bar to visible and when it ends I switch the visibilities of play button and a progress bar. Although, I use `INVISIBLE`, not `GONE`, because `GONE` makes my layout move up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make transparent button (background="@null") and place it on the ProgressBar using RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.

This is simpler than it seems:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="asdasd"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Make the same in code if you want.

Comment: updated...hope this helps, how to make this simpler, unfortunately I do not know

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the `Button` here? Mb it's enough to place the `ProgressBar` only and make it clickable by setting `onClickListener`.

Comment: Да нет, у меня полноценный плеер, без кнопочек никак не обойтись =)

Comment: Да сделай ты обычную красивую кнопку со статическим бэкграундом и не парься :)

Comment: Так и сделала. В определенное время давала visible для одно и invisible для другого ;)